# Developing own packages: UseMethod won't work

Tags: r, package

In my own package, which works absolutely fine, I include three new functions:

```
#' @export
myfunc <- function(object, ...) {
  UseMethod("myfunc", object)
}

#' @export
myfunc.formula <- function(formula, data, ...) {
  ...
}

#' @export
myfunc.default <- function(x, y, ...) {
  ...
}
```

After compiling the package, I'm able to run myfunc.formula() and myfunc.default(), but trying to run myfunc() results in an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("myfunc") : 
  no applicable method for 'myfunc' applied to an object of class "formula".
```

Also, methods(myfunc) find all two functions.

What went wrong or what is missed? All functions are exported.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Include `S3method(myfun)` in file `NAMESPACE`. Or run `devtools::document()` to convert roxigen comments into .Rd files.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I must delete NAMESPACE file, so that devtools is able to recreate it